# Is my MongoDB index corrupt? adding additional query parameter increases the found documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing

My query is failing to find all matching results. If I add an additional `_id` parameter to a specific matching example, I am getting results

```
> db.reviews.count({"contentProvider":"GLORP", "responses.0": {$exists: true}})
0
> db.reviews.count({_id: "1234", "contentProvider":"GLORP", "responses.0": {$exists: true}})
1
```

the first query is using index:

```
"indexName" : "contentProvider_1_reviewDetail_1_reviewerUserName_1_providerReviewId_1",
```

and the query with the `_id` is of course using the `_id_` index:

```
"indexName" : "_id_"
```

Here is the index in question:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "contentProvider" : 1,
        "reviewDetail" : 1,
        "reviewerUserName" : 1,
        "providerReviewId" : 1
    },
    "name" : "contentProvider_1_reviewDetail_1_reviewerUserName_1_providerReviewId_1",
    "ns" : "test.reviews",
    "background" : true
}
```

Using mongodb version `3.2.3`

Is the index corrupted? Will dropping it and readding it likely fix the problem?

Comment: Well, _something_ seems broken and it seems likely that it's your index.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and you could certainly try it, however without knowing what version of MongoDB you are using and without seeing the index definition I cannot say for certain.

There are multiple different types of indexes as well as index properties like: [sparse](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) or [partial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/) that can change behavior and may explain why the index doesn't return the results you expect.

I'd recommend checking the index first and see if the index definition has any properties that would result in the document being excluded.

If not then you can always drop the index and recreate it.

Comment: I updated with the index description and mongodb version

Comment: I could be mistaken here but the index you outline doesn't include the responses field. So the index is likely being used for the query but it also has to go back to the collection for full comparison. If the collection is large and you just added the index (in the background) it's possible it has not been fully built. You can check with db.currentOp() and see if the index is still being built. If not then it would seem like you do have a bad index and it should be dropped and re-added.

Comment: Yeah, the fact this particular index was used was coincidental. I wasn't trying to perform a performant query. Its an old index. Either way, it seems like the index is corrupted.